# Horizontal axis doesn't seem to have a value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so i'm trying to achieve a player thats stops whenever the user lets go of the key, i don't want it to slide, i have a `vertical` variable and a `horizontal` variable that stores the axis, if these values are less or more than zero, than the bool `isMoving` is set to true, else it's set to false, this works wonderful on the vertical azis but not on the horizontal axis, i tried even making if statements checking when the keys are pressed and when they are not

like this

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) 
{
    isMoving = true;
}

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) 
{
    isMoving = true;
}

if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)) 
{
    isMoving = false;
}

if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)) 
{
    isMoving = false;
}
```

this also did not work,

this is my script:

```
  using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("Player Values")]
    [SerializeField] private float playerSpeed = 50f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight = 7f;

    [Header("Ground Check")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask ground;
    private float checkLenght = 0.1f;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private float horizontal;
    private float vertical;

    // Crouch Scales
    private Vector3 initialScale;
    private Vector3 crouchScale;

    // Counter Movement
    private bool isMoving;
    private bool isOnGround;
    private float counterDrag = 10f;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Crouch Scales
        initialScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
        crouchScale = new Vector3(1f, 0.5f, 1f);

        // Player Movement
        MovePlayer();

        // Counter Movement
        ApplyCounterMovement();

        // Check Ground
        isOnGround = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, checkLenght, ground);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        CheckInput();
    }
    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerSpeed;
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerSpeed;

        Vector3 movement = transform.forward * vertical + transform.right * horizontal;

        rb.AddForce(movement, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }

    private void CheckInput()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            getDown();
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            getUp();
        }

        // Check Counter Movement

        if (horizontal > 0f || horizontal < 0f)
        {
            isMoving = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isMoving = false;
        }

        if (vertical > 0f || vertical < 0f)
        {
            isMoving = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isMoving = false;
        }

        // Check Jump
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    // Crouch
    private void getDown()
    {
        transform.localScale = crouchScale;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.5f, transform.position.z);
    }

    // Get Up From Crouching
    private void getUp()
    {
        transform.localScale = initialScale;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z);
    }

    // Apply Counter Movement
    private void ApplyCounterMovement()
    {
        if(isMoving == true)
        {
            rb.drag = 0f;
            return;
        }
        if(isMoving == false)
        {
            rb.drag = counterDrag;
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        if (isOnGround == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(isOnGround == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your vertical handling if statement is after the horizontal one, and they both set the isMoving variable, it is effectively saying "if the user isn't pressing down or up, then there is no movement at all". Try deleting those two if statements, and use `isMoving = (horizontal > 0f || horizontal < 0f || vertical > 0f || vertical < 0f);`

Comment: I recommend learning [how to use the Unity debugger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html). It would help you find the cause of problems like this very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if checks for the vertical into overrule the ones before for the horizontal since both of them set the same field `isMoving`.

Rather combine them into e.g.

```
isMoving = horizontal != 0f || vertical != 0f;
```